# In vscode-go, is there a way to run the local version of a tool for go:generate statements?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In many projects, I have a `tools/tools.go` file that allows me to have local versions of the tools I use ([reference](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-can-i-track-tool-dependencies-for-a-module)).

I also have `go:generate` statements in my code to automate the generation of mock files using https://github.com/golang/mock/mockgen. I have a local version of `mockgen` under a `bin` folder of my project and I can generate all the mocks of my project by running something like `PATH=./bin:${PATH} go generate ./...`.

Vscode-go recognizes the `go:generate` statements in the code and can generate code for us.

[image: vscode-go generate helper]

I would like to know if there is a way to get vscode-go to run `mockgen` (through `gopls.generate`) using the local version I have under the `bin` directory.

With the setting `go.alternateTools`, vscode-go lets us specify an alternate path for the tools used by the extension (i.e. `dlv`). I tried to configure that option for `mockgen` but it didn't change anything. My guess is that it does not work because vscode-go runs `mockgen` through `gopls.generate`; it does not run `mockgen` directly. But this is just a guess.

Below is the error I get if I don't have a `mockgen` binary in my `$PATH`:

```
[Info  - 5:44:18 PM] 2021/08/08 17:44:18 xxxxxxx.go:19: running "mockgen": exec: "mockgen": executable file not found in $PATH

    operation="generate"
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Edit: see @Zyl's comment [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68699272/in-vscode-go-is-there-a-way-to-run-the-local-version-of-a-tool-for-gogenerate?noredirect=1#comment121419602_68699272) for a very good alternative.

Comment: Why don't you just invoke the local mockgen binary with your go generate statement? e.g. `//go:generate ../bin/mockgen [...]` ?

Comment: @Zyl I didn't think about it but it's a great idea. In the end, my goal is to make sure everyone run the same version of a given tool in my project. And what you proposed is perfect for that purpose since it doesn't rely on any IDE configuration. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the same problem today. Found this solution, which worked for me if someone needs this in future:

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/go" 
export PATH="$GOPATH/bin:$PATH"
```

And then run (in the directory where file with the "go:generate" comment is located)

```
go generate
```